# Can I convert a USDZ to solid mesh such as stl

Tags: xcode, arkit, 3d-modelling, usdz

I used an ios app to create a usdz file using arkit but now I want to convert the scan to a solid 3d model such as an stl or obj. is there an ios or mac application that allows for this conversion. I cannot find any app that can open them other than xcode and preview but neither allow me to export to a 3d model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ModelIO` can](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391813-canimportfileextension), at least in iOS.

```
import ModelIO

let usdz = URL(fileURLWithPath: "model.usdz")
let asset = MDLAsset(url: usdz)
let stl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "model.stl")
try asset.export(to: stl)
```

`.usdz` is just a zipped `.usdc` file with textures (from the offical [documentation](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/Usdz-File-Format-Specification.html)).
If you want to export the file on a mac, change the file extension to `.zip`, unzip the file and use `ModelIO` to export a `.stl` file.

Open Xcode, create a new Playground, choose macOS as the platform. I have downloaded a test file from [Apple's Quick Look Gallery](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/gallery/), and unzipped an example to `stratocoaster_usdz/` in my Downlaods directory. Then use the following code:

```
import ModelIO

// Get the path to the Downloads directory in your home folder
let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let usdc = URL(fileURLWithPath: "stratocaster_usdz/Stratocaster.usdc", relativeTo: directory)

// Load the usdc file that was packed in the usdz file
let asset = MDLAsset(url: usdc)

do {
    let target = URL(fileURLWithPath: "stratocaster.stl", relativeTo: directory)
    // Export to .stl
    try asset.export(to: target)
} catch {
    error
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for.
I created a Mac OS script to automate this in Terminal.  I also did something similar in an Automator Quick Action to run from Finder with a RightClick on the file, but couldn't figure out a way to attach that here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript

// Save to a file, e.g. usdz2stl.js
// chmod +x usdz2stl.js
// usdz2stl.js /path/to/model.usdz

ObjC.import('ModelIO')

function run(argv) {
  var inFile = argv[0];
  var outFile = inFile + ".stl";
  console.log("Converting " + inFile + " ...");
  var usdz = $.NSURL.alloc.initFileURLWithPath(inFile);
  var asset = $.MDLAsset.alloc.initWithURL(usdz);
  var stl = $.NSURL.alloc.initFileURLWithPath(outFile);
  asset.exportAssetToURL(stl);
  console.log("Conversion Complete: " + outFile);
}
```

Comment: i've tryd your script. unfortunatelly I get an error: ./usdz2stl.js:440:489: script error: Error on line 16: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of script (-2700). Got it: I forgot to copy the } at the end

Answer (score 4):

Simply directly open .USDZ or USDC file in XCODE

If you have unzipped the .zip you will keep an .USDC file and a folder called "0" which contains all the textures, materials, alpha in .PNG.

Once opened .USDZ or .USDC in XCODE >> File >> Export

You can directly choose the main .OBJ .STL formats and many others

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately exporting it to DAE or OBJ crashes the Xcode